# Installation of draw2D touch on Angular2

Tags: angular, draw2d-js

how can I install the draw2d touch library on Angular 2 ? 
I do not find any news about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the library's files in the scripts section of your angular-cli.json. In your component you can write:

```
declare var draw2d:any;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the npm package listed here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/draw2d-wrapper

My project was an Angular4 project built from using angular cli.  I added the require statement in the lib.ts file as shown in the readme. Then within the xxx.component.ts file I again followed the readme and added this statement:

```
let draw2d = (<any>window).draw2d;
```

This allowed me access to the draw2d library.

Answer (score 0):

You can install using either npm or bower.

- npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/draw2d-wrapper

  `npm install -g draw2d-wrapper`
- bower package: https://github.com/freegroup/draw2d_js.bower

  `bower install draw2d`

Comment: It says that package is now deprecated and the documentation has been removed from git!